# how to show the retrieve data from database in td without refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

i having a drop down box, it have two client(ex:client,client),i have more then 2000 data in each client table ,when selecting client i want to retrieve all data from database and show it in front end that in HTML table with out refreshing can any one help me how to do that

my Dropdown code:

```
<select name="client" id="client" style="margin:-24px 0 0 1px;background-color:#E8E8E8;width:104px;position: absolute;"> 
   <option value="">Select Client</option>
<?php

$sql=mysql_query("select * from client_list");

$clientid=$_GET['clientid'];
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))    
{
    if(strlen($_GET['clientid'])>0 && $_GET['clientid']==$row['clientid']){
    print' <option id="client" name="client" value="'.$row['clientid'].'" selected>'.$row['clientid'].' </option>';}

    else{

            print' <option id="client" name="client" value="'.$row['clientid'].'" >'.$row['clientid'].' </option>';
    }
       }
   ?>
</select>
```

Ajax

```
<script>
$(function() {    document.ready
    $("#client").on("change", function() {
        var ID=$(this).attr('id');
        var clientid=$("#client").val();
        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            data: {
                clientselect: $(this).val()
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $("#display").html(data);
                window.location = '?action=clientnetworkpricelist&clientid='+clientid+'';
                $("#flash").hide();
            }
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: What is `document.ready` doing at the beginning of the function? That's not valid Javascript syntax. Was that supposed to be a comment?

Comment: You're missing the URL of the AJAX server script.

Comment: can you please write down code for me

Comment: We're not here to write code for you, we're here to help you fix the problems in your code.

Comment: ok you mean like this url:xxx.com+ "?action=clientnetworkpricelist&clientid='+clientid+'", can you tell me i am doing right

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the URL in the AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "server.php",
    type: "post",
    data: {
        clientsel: $(this).val()
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $("#display").html(data);
        window.location = '?action=clientnetworkpricelist&clientid='+clientid+'';
        $("#flash").hide();
    }
});
```

`server.php` should perform the appropriate database query, and output the HTML that you want to be put into the `display` DIV.